# passing a function as a parameter

Tags: c, function, parameters, function-pointers, function-parameter

```
void dispatch_for(dispatch_queue_t *queue, long number, void (* work)(long)){
    int loop = number;
    int i;
    task_t *ctask;
    for(i = 0; i<loop;i++){
        ctask = create_task((void *)work,number,"for_test");
        dispatch_async(queue,ctask);
    }
}    

task_t *task_create(void (* work)(void *), void *param, char* name){

    //do something
}
```

I'm getting work as a function and need to pass it to the function create_task..(1st parameter)
How should i pass it?

Comment: Are `create_task` and `task_create` supposed to be the same function ?

Comment: What's the error/problem? You should be able to just pass `work` verbatim. Also check your spelling, is it `task_create` or `create_task`? Best though to say `typedef void (*workfunction)(void*);`, then you can cast `(workfunction)work` if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

name of the function without the parentheses is the pointer to that function :

```
void work(void) {
...;
}

void main(void) {
task_create(work, void, void);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to forward the ingress parameter `work`, but it has a slightly different type.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the identifier like any other parameter:

```
dispatch_for(queue, number, work);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C, and `work` is a type `void (*)(long)`, but you want to make it a `void (*)(void*)`, simply re-cast the type of `work` (this is can be done the easiest by using a typedef)

```
//declare somewhere at a global level
typedef void (*task_create_func)(void*);

//at the point where you want to call task_create
task_create((task_create_func)work, PARAM1, PARM2);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with typedefs, you can simply do the cast using the desired pointer-type at the point-of-call like so:

```
task_create((void (*)(void*))work, PARAM1, PARAM2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be a typedef to the wanted function type. So you can do

```
typedef void workfunc_t(void *);

workfunc_t sample_workfunc; // in order to ensure type-correctness

void workfunc_t(void *)
{
    // ...
}

void dispatch_for(dispatch_queue_t *queue, long number, workfunc_t * work)
{
    int loop = number;
    int i;
    task_t *ctask;
    for(i = 0; i<loop;i++) {
        ctask = create_task(work, number, "for_test");
        dispatch_async(queue,ctask);
    }
}

task_t *task_create(workfunc_t work, void *param, char* name){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `work` doesn't have the same signature in `dispatch_for` and `task_create` (the argument is a pointer in one, a long in the other)

It seems strange you want to use the same function in both cases